# Do I need to hit, or just attack, to trigger Defensive Rebuke?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, attack, tome-of-battle

How does the Defensive Rebuke crusader maneuver from the *Tome of Battle* trigger? Do I need to hit my enemy to trigger the effect, or does even rolling the attack dice and failing to touch the enemy apply the debuff?

What I'm unclear on is the meaning of “strike”:

> Each enemy you **strike** after you initiate this maneuver…

Does “strike” means hitting and dealing damage? Or just making an attack?

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84476/4563)—this use of the word “strike” is not unique to this maneuver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The descriptive text says (*Tome of Battle, p58*)

> ...when your blows strike home...

and the rules text says 'strike' not 'attack', so RAW it's mostly clear that you have to hit, and RAI it's crystal clear; you have to hit the target.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between *strike* (= hit) and *strike at* (= aim towards).

Striking the enemy means obtaining a success on the *to hit* roll.